# Google Cloud Storage - Invalid Blob Key Error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have uploaded a video file to Google Cloud Storage bucket by invoking the following call in an upload Java Servlet.

```
UploadOptions opts = UploadOptions.Builder
            .withGoogleStorageBucketName(GCS_BUCKET_NAME);
String url = blobstore.createUploadUrl(UPLOAD_PATH, opts);
```

When I try to download the file through a download Java Servlet, invalid blob key exception is thrown.

Following are the steps carried out to download the file.

1. Url is converted to `/gs/bucketname/filename` and passed to `createGsBlobKey` function.
2. When the received blob key is passed to `new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey)` the said exception is thrown out.

The same set of code is working for Development environment without any error. I can view and download the files from Google developers console also.

I have verified the `bucketname`, `filename`. Both matches with the developers console name. I can't figure out what's wrong with the approach.

Anybody from Google App Engine team please shed some light on what's happening behind.

The stack trace is attached here. Thanks!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By6jpKO3DnIsRld1WUIwNk1mWXc

Comment: Do you see your file successfully uploaded in the storage viewer? If you do, what code do you use to download it?

Comment: Hi, following is the code snippet used to retrieve the blob data 
`String gsName = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"); log.info("GS path: " + gsName); BlobKey videoBlobKey = blobstore.createGsBlobKey(gsName); inputStream = new BlobstoreInputStream(videoBlobKey);`. I have verified the file path and the log message both are matching 100%.

Comment: I even tried using `GcsService` to retrieve the file content `GcsFilename gcsfileName = getGcsFileName(gsName); GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(gcsfileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);`. In this case I got a null pointer exception when the data is read.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Yes, I verified the file in storage viewer. I can download the file. What I could not understand is if the file path `/gs/bucket/filepath` is not correct, how a `BlobKey` is received? If a `BlobKey` is received for a valid path, then why Invalid Blob Key error is thrown when it was accessed?

Comment: Blobstore is called a "superseded storage solution" in the documentation. It can be discontinued at any time. Why not use Java Client library for GCS without Blobstore?